# Left Shift and Right Shift to prevent division loss

Tags: c, integer, division, pic, 16-bit

I was not allowed to use floating point variables in my C code (for performance reasons). I wanted to perform a integer division operation and at the same time I want to prevent the division loss as much as possible.

My understanding is, if the numerator is a large number, the division operation will yield good results. Currently I'm doing a left shift operation on the numerator to make it a big number and then I divide the numerator by the denominator. In the final result, I'm doing right shift to compensate my original left shift operation. My question is, will this improve the division results?

For example to achieve `x = y / z`, I'm writing my "C" code as follows,

```
x = y << 4;
x = x / z;
x = x >> 4;
```

Comment: No, it will not change anything (except of some performance loss). Everything you have gained by scaling up, you lose when scaling back down. And you can easily verify it by running some tests instead of asking.

Comment: "Division loss" is caused by the quotient being a non-integer value, which obviously can't fit in an integer.  What exactly do you want `x` to contain when you're done?

Comment: The only case this technique might help is when you want to increase the precision of some *intermediate* calculations, working all the way with scaled up quantities and scaling down only in the end.

Comment: I just have a simple equation out = out * (ratio_n/ratio_d). I made my code as     // Interpolate
   out = val[i] - val[i - 1];
    out = (out * ratio_n) << 2;
    out = (out / ratio_d) >> 2;
    out = out + val[i - 1];

Comment: Your code would make more sense if you did some rounding.  maybe by adding 0x08 before shifting x right.  But then, this all depends on context.  Maybe the best route to follow is to use algorithms that don't require division.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly by division loss?

If you want a rounding division, such as `div(19,10) -> 2`, and you know `x` and `y` are positive, you can do this:

```
(x + y / 2) / y
```

The division by `2` is very efficient compared to a division by `y`, unless `y` is a compile time constant, in which case, the division will be compiled into a multiplication plus an adjustment.

You must also avoid division overflow, such as division by `0` or division of `INT_MIN` by `-1`.

If you want to compute a scaling, you must perform the multiplication **before** the division:

```
out = out * ratio_n / ratio_d;
```

`*` and `/` have the same precedence and are left associative, which means `a * b / c` is parsed as `(a * b) / c`.

You might need to use a larger type for the intermediary result:

```
out = (long long)out * ratio_n / ratio_d;
```

And you can combine both techniques:

```
out = ((long long)out * ratio_n + ratio_d / 2) / ratio_d;
```

If your system has 16-bit `int`s, you should just use `long` as the intermediary type as it is guaranteed to have at least 32 bits:

```
out = ((long)out * ratio_n + ratio_d / 2) / ratio_d;
```

Note however that if the result exceeds the range of type `int`, the behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: When `x` or `y` are negative, `(x + y / 2) / y` needs work.

Comment: @chux: good point. Negative values are a pain for this question, I cannot think of an elegant way to handle them correctly.

Comment: @chux: Curiously this might be an exception. At least if the PIC tag happens to refer to the PIC18 architecture with the C18 compiler. The only C implementation I have encountered which takes advantage of the C89 leeway in rounding modes, worse it is also the only implementation I know of not sign-extending right shifts.

Comment: @doynax: for some reason, I knew I shouldn't use `y >> 1` to avoid potential undefined behavior ;-)

Comment: I understood the division loss i'm thinking is associated with rounding the values. I resolved my issue using the below technique which works for both positive and negative number.     `out <<= 1;
    out /= ratio_d;
    out += (out < 0) ? - 1 : 1;
    out >>= 1;`

Comment: @Anand: yes, this method works if `out << 1` does not cause an arithmetic overflow (technically, it has undefined behavior for negative numbers, so you should write `out += out;`  or `out = out * 2 / ratio_d`.  Your adjustment trick does not work as expected, even if `ratio_d` is positive only: it relies on right shifting negative numbers with sign replication, which is not guaranteed by the standard, furthermore adjustment is not needed for negative values as `-1 >> 1` -> `-1`.